# How to test run a Bamboo deployment from a different branch?

Tags: bamboo, bamboo-specs

We are using Bamboo Deployment Projects configured in our `bamboo.yml`:

```
# ...
---
version: 2

deployment:
  name: MyDeployment
  source-plan: MYPLAN
environments:
 - Dev
Dev:
  tasks:
    - script: echo "hi"
# ...
```

Now suppose I create a git branch and I change the deployment task in the yml file.
How do I create a deployment to test my new deployment task before I merge it?

If I push this branch, run the build for the plan branch, check that "bamboo specs execution successful" and create a release, then if I deploy the release still the deploy script from the master branch is used.

Yaml format: https://docs.atlassian.com/bamboo-specs-docs/9.4.0/specs.html?yaml#release-naming

Deployment projects: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/deployment-projects-338363438.html

Comment: Not seeing such a feature in the UI is a red flag that It's just not supported.

Comment: @Alex Not necessarily, even if there is no direct 'run my yml' button it might still be possible by creating a linked repository manually for example

Comment: Nothing will help you use that repo for one branch and another repo for another branch within the same deployment. Deployments just don't have a notion of branches. Alas. Creating a separate deployment for each branch need is the way we do it.

Comment: "Plan branch configuration is not available for deployment projects. Bamboo ignores any Bamboo Specs on deployment projects in plan branches." Found at https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/enhanced-plan-branch-configuration-1018767259.html

Comment: @Alex Thanks! That answers my question. I now found some related feature requests: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-14013 and https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-15155 and https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BAM-21299